# clikjacking Implementation issue

Tags: content-security-policy, clickjacking

I have added the following meta tag to avoid clickjacking in my website.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
```

But it throws "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-CwE3Bg0VYQOIdNAkbB/Btdkhul49qZuwgNCMPgNY5zw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

Comment: Have you checked out: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

Answer (score 0):

Add

`style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'`

Or move the inline CSS to an external file. However, it's incredibly common to allow inline styles even though there is some risk involved.